# Multipart request rejected by Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data, webrequest

I'm trying to send a Multipart request to a Web API using `HttpWebRequest`. The request I'm sending has the following format:

```
----------636194206488346738
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="A.png"
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
{Binary data in here}
----------636194206488346738--
{new line at the end}
```

And the request configuration is as follows:

```
Content-Type:"multipart/form-data; boundary=----------636194206488346738
Method: POST
Keep-Alive: True
```

When sending the request to the web API I get the `Invalid end of stream error`. However, I tried to convert the stream to text to see the actual data and it matches the example I added above.

However, when I'm using the `WebClient` and call the `UploadFile` method for the same purpose, I can successfully upload files to the API without any problem suggesting that something is wrong with my approach which is as follows.

**My Constants:**

```
Boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BoundaryDelimiter + Boundary;
BeginContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + Boundary + "\r\n");
EndContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + Boundary + "--\r\n");
```

**Method for formatting form data:**

```
private Byte[] FormDataFormat(String name, String fileName, String contentType)
        => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type:{2}\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n", name, fileName, contentType));
```

**Attaching file to a stream:**

```
Stream = new MemoryStream();
foreach (var i in files) {
    var tempEncode = FormDataFormat("file", i, "application/octet-stream");
    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(i); // Files are supposed to be small.
    Stream.Write(BeginContent, 0, BeginContent.Length);
    Stream.Write(tempEncode, 0, tempEncode.Length);
    Stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    ContentLenght += BeginContent.Length + tempEncode.Length + file.Length;
}
Stream.Write(EndContent, 0, EndContent.Length);
ContentLenght += EndContent.Length;
```

**Creating the request:**

```
public HttpWebRequest Request(String method) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = ContentType;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentLength = ContentLenght;
        Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Stream.CopyTo(request.GetRequestStream());
        Stream.Dispose();
        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown in your question the `BoundaryDelimiter` variable declaration but for the purpose of this answer I will assume that it is defined like this:

```
BoundaryDelimiter = "---------------------"
```

Now the problem with your code is that you are missing a couple of dashes (`--`) when calculating your boundary delimiters in order to conform to [`RFC2388`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt).

So instead of:

```
BeginContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + Boundary + "\r\n");
EndContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + Boundary + "--\r\n");
```

You need this:

```
BeginContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + "--" + Boundary + "\r\n");
EndContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n" + BoundaryDelimiter + "--" + Boundary + "--\r\n");
```

Notice the additional `--` that I have added to your begin and end content boundary delimiters.

Check the example [`provided here`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

Notice how the boundary is equal to `AaB03x` but the delimiter is actually `--AaB03x` and of course the end delimiter is `--AaB03x--`.

As a side note you could get rid of the `ContentLenght` variable (which you have misspelled by the way :-)) and remove this line:

```
request.ContentLength = ContentLenght
```

This will simplify your code as the `HttpWebRequest` class will automatically populate the `Content-Length` header depending on the number of bytes you have written to the request stream.

This being said, I would recommend you using the `HttpClient` class instead of `HttpWebRequest` because it already has built-in capabilities for properly encoding this kind of stuff. It will definitely make your code more readable as you will not have to worry about boundaries, delimiters and content lengths.

Comment: I just noticed that moments before seeing your answer. :)